# Rails5 app loses session after capistrano deploy to Passenger / Apache env, works fine on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, capistrano, passenger, rvm-capistrano

I manage a dozen or so Rails apps that all use Capistrano & Passenger.

I noticed that when I deploy an update to a Rails 5 app users get logged out, i.e. the session is lost. Apps that use Rails 4 or earlier don't, users stay logged in ; the session handling is all cookies in all cases (defaults).

I this related to different versions of Rails or Passenger ? Any ideas how to fix it ?

Here is the deploy.rb piece:

```rb
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{release_path}/tmp"
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart
end
```

and I am using

```
  * capistrano (3.13.0)
  * capistrano-bundler (1.6.0)
  * capistrano-rails (1.1.8)
  * capistrano-rails-console (2.3.0)
  * capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
```

To deploy: `cap production deploy`

Thanks in advance for your help.
Patrick

Comment: What do you exactly do when you deploy a rails5 app with cap (e.g. what are the tasks that are done, especially if you have custom tasks)? There could be something that overrides the key that is used for checking the integrity of cookies.

Comment: Thank you for your response @pduersteler - I have included the deploy.rb snippet above - how do you set the key used to check cookie integrity ?

Answer (score 1):

I think my problem was due to a change in Rails 5.2, the introduction of `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` to take over from `secrets.yml`

Because the Rails 5 app I created was using 5.2, the generator did not create a `secrets.yml` file anymore - but also the master.key setting was not enabled:

```rb
  # config.require_master_key = true
```

I assume that as a result of this Rails used some transient key to sign the cookies - which changed whenever the server was restarted.

I have now re-added  `config/secrets.yml` to my project and from my testing it seems the problem has disappeared.